# Is there a function that is continuously differentiable but not proper?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

A convex function $f$ is called **proper** if
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\exists x ,f(x)<+\infty,\\
\forall x ,f(x)>-\infty.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

My question is:

Is it possible that $f$ is continuously differentiable but not proper?

Comment: How do you define (continuous) differentiability for functions that are possibly equal to $+$ or $-$ infinity at some points?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio My opinion is: (1) a proper convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ may not continuously differentiable, such as $f(x)=-\ln x(x>0),f(x)=+\infty(x\leq0)$. (2) a continuously differentiable convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ must proper. If there exists a point a such that $f(a)=+\infty$, this means that $f$ is discontinuous at $a$, is this right?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of "continuously differentiable".

In a certain sense, the function $f \colon \mathbb R \to \bar{\mathbb R}$ with $f(x) = -\log(x)$ for $x > 0$, $f(x) = \infty$ for $x \le 0$ qualifies.
In fact:

- We could say that it is continuous, because $\lim_{y \to x} f(y) = f(x)$ holds for **all** $x \in \mathbb R$, if we allow $+\infty$ as a limit.
- It is differentiable at all $x \in \operatorname{dom} f$. This is the best we can hope for, since the definition of differentiability at $x$ needs $f(x) < \infty$.
- The derivative $f' \colon \operatorname{dom} f \to \mathbb R$ is continuous.